# Returning boolean value in an rxjs function fails

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Am new to the rxjs and i would like to return an observable of either true or false

this is what i have tried

```
checkLoggedin():Observable<boolean> {
  //check from server if user is loggdin
  if(this._tokenService.getToken()){ //this returns synchronous true or false

      this._httpservice.checkifloggedin()
         .subscribe((res)=>{
            return res.data //this comes in as true or false value
              },
              err=>{ return false }
              )    
     }else{

        return false  //this fails with an error of 
                    //type false is not assignable to observable<boolean>
        }

 }
```

How do i change the above else part to work with the boolean observable so that in the other components i can only do

```
this._authservice.checkLoggedin()
  .subscribe.....//here get the value whether true or false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `return Observable.of(false)` instead of `return false`.

Comment: This return the value instantly, you want to emit it, when then you httpservice returns data.

Comment: @Oisin, Actually no, look closer, he returns `false` syncronously.

Comment: @GEOFFREY MWANGI, Also you should not subscribe in your `checkLoggedin` function, because then you return `subscribtion` instead of `observable`. You need to use `map`, see @Skeptor 's answer.

Answer (score 5):

this should work

```
checkLoggedin():Observable<boolean> { 
  if(this._tokenService.getToken()){ 
    return this._httpservice.checkifloggedin().map(res=>res.data ) ;
  } else { 
    return Observable.of(false);
  }
}
```